# Error Deserializing XML (C#): There is an error in XML document (2, 2) (but XmlSerializer created it)

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I know, I know questions on failure to deserialize XML with error "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)." are littered across the internet but I'm still stumped.

I have an XML document created using XmlSerializer from a c# class. This document is failing to deserialize with Exception:

```
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
Inner Exception: The server could not be contacted.
Root inner exception: The LDAP server is unavailable.
```

I am using XmlSerializer to both serialise and deserialize and strangely, the XML document in question can be deserialized using the same code on another computer.

I use the following code to serialise and deserialize classes I have generated in C#:

```
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string filename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with XmlReader");

        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type and namespace.
        XmlSerializer serializer = new
        XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        xml.XmlReader reader = xml.XmlReader.Create(fs);

        // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
        T i;

        // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        i = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        fs.Close();
        return i;
    }

    public static void WriteObject<T>(T value, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename);
        serializer.Serialize(tw, value);
        tw.Close();
    }
```

The XML document is stored locally at:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\myapp\myxmldoc.xml

and follows this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id xsi:nil="true" />
  <Property1>text</Property1>
  <Property2>0000000</Property2>
  <Property3>
    <Property31>
      <Property311>text</Property311>
      <Property312>text</Property312>
    </Property31>    
  </Property3>  
  <Property4 />
  <Property5>false</Property5>
</MyClass>
```

I use the following code to deserialize:

```
myclassvar = SerialiseXML.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(xmldocpath);
```

Other classes are serialising to, and deserializing from, XML just fine on the offending computer.

Oh and for kicks I ran the code through a validator which found no faults.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that "The LDAP server is unavailable."

Comment: Also, you're missing `using` blocks on your Stream, XmlReader and TextWriter.

Comment: While using an XML document, an entirely unrelated error happened. XML stuff just happens to be on the top of the call stack where the error was handled and reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your error message, it looks like the The LDAP server is unavailable because it could not be contacted. This is likely caused by a property in the class you are deserializing making a call to an LDAP server when its value is set. Take the following code for example, which will fail to connect to the server while deserializing if the server name is invalid:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestData
{
   private bool connect;

   private TcpClient connection;

   public string ServerName {get; set;}

   public bool ConnectToServer { 
       get { return this.connect; }
       set { 
          if (this.connect = value)
          {
              this.connection = new TcpConnection(this.ServerName, 8080);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That is what was so confusing. I was adamant I was not calling a LDAP server but you are right : )

Comment: Stupid interface wont let me press enter here without posting, but in a constructor for a property of "MyClass" I was getting the display name of the logged in user (i.e. this.WindowsDisplayName = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;) and the username (this.WindowsUsername = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;). This was causing the problem as it could not get these (or probably just the name) offline. Thanks! Unfortunately due to my lack of Karma I cannot upvote your answer but I implore all that pass here to upvote it : )